# TexStudio doesn't register math mode for TikZ "matrix of math nodes"

Tags: math-mode, texstudio, syntax-highlighting

In TexStudio, when I make a diagram with TikZ and use the `matrix of math nodes` option, it doesn't register that it's supposed to look like math mode... so it ends up having a bunch of highlighting for "wrong syntax" everywhere. For instance, in the text below, the `&`, `\times`, and `^` are all highlighted because everything registers as normal text.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes]
    {   A    & B\times B'  \\  
        C^n  & D           \\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

So it ends up looking like this:

[image: annoying syntax highlighting]

instead of something more like this (my settings make math bolded):

[image: what I want instead]

You might ask, "Couldn't you just surround the diagram with math delimiters?" But that doesn't seem quite right... and in fact I am also asking this question because I'm using a package (based on the `diagrams` package I think) which defines a new environment using such a TikZ matrix, and it breaks if you add extra delimiters for some reason I haven't figured out. Why is this highlighting occurring, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. What is, please, your minimal complete code?

Comment: @Sebastiano Oops, sorry, I edited the original post and made the code complete!